# isinstance(foo, types.GeneratorType) or inspect.isgenerator(foo)?

Tags: python, performance

It seems that there are two ways in Python to test whether an object is a generator:

```
import types
isinstance(foo, types.GeneratorType)
```

or:

```
import inspect
inspect.isgenerator(foo)
```

In the spirit of "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.", is one of these ways recommended over the other (presumably they do the same thing...if not, please enlighten me!)?

Comment: Why do you want to check it in the first place?

Comment: isgenerator I think is more for a function(that hasnt been called) whereas isinstance typically refers to an instanciated generator that has been returned or constructed by something (thats my 2c on the matter)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: fair question, obviously type checking to be avoided in Python. I have a function which in 99% of the time iterates twice through a list. In the 1% of the time that a generator is passed in I need to crystalise it as a list before doing so.

Comment: Pretty sure they do the same thing.  I don't think it matters which you use but I think `isinstance(foo, types.GeneratorType)` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @Joran: `types.isgenerator` is exactly `return isinstance(object, types.GeneratorType)`, so no... it doesn't return different results..

Comment: I'm not sure if `itertools.tee()` is smart enough to detect non-iterators but if it does that might be a good choice instead of trying to detect if the argument is an iterator.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: yeah, I thought of that. And it works (although not sure it 'intelligently' handles non-iterators). But, from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) of `itertools.tee`: in general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use `list()` instead of `tee()`. Which is my case.

Comment: I think a better solution is to document that the function doesn't work with a generator, that it requires a container object of some sort. The caller can then call it with `list(gen)` or whatever in the case that they have a generator.

Comment: @kindall: would be better but I don't control the calling code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are 100% equivalent:

```
>>> print(inspect.getsource(inspect.isgenerator))
def isgenerator(object):
    """Return true if the object is a generator.

    Generator objects provide these attributes:
        __iter__        defined to support interation over container
        close           raises a new GeneratorExit exception inside the
                        generator to terminate the iteration
        gi_code         code object
        gi_frame        frame object or possibly None once the generator has
                        been exhausted
        gi_running      set to 1 when generator is executing, 0 otherwise
        next            return the next item from the container
        send            resumes the generator and "sends" a value that becomes
                        the result of the current yield-expression
        throw           used to raise an exception inside the generator"""
    return isinstance(object, types.GeneratorType)
```

I'd say that using `isinstance(object, types.GeneratorType)` should be the preferred way since it's clearer and simpler.
Also `inspect.isgenerator` was only added in python2.6, which means that using `isinstance` is more backward compatible.

They probably added the `isgenerator` function for symmetry [`isgeneratorfunction`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isgeneratorfunction) which does something different.

Comment: +1 for alerting me to the `getsource` function in the `inspect` module. That's cool!

Comment: I suspect the reason it was added is so that it can be passed as second argument to `inspect.getmembers`, allowing you to iterate through an objects attributes, finding only (say) generator objects.

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr It could be. The other obvious option would be to use `partial` but in order to pass only the second argument you'd have to use keyword args, which I believe aren't supported by `isinstance`, hence the only other way would be to use a `lambda`(which is exactly the same as passing `isgenerator`).

Answer (score 2):

You can do type checking, but you probably don't want to check for *just* generators.  what you really want is to check for 'iterators.', or rather, you want two iterators.

```
import collections, itertools

def cheap_tee(foo):
    if isinstance(foo, collections.Iterator):
        # this is already an iterator, we need to 'tee' it
        return itertools.tee(foo)
    elif isinstance(foo, collections.Iterable):
        # this is already an iterable, get two iterators from it:
        return iter(foo), iter(foo)
    raise TypeError("Don't know how to cheaply copy these", foo)
```

This will then work on *anything* that is remotely iterable, not just generator expressions.  Some types will provide custom iterators that work on data structures that are not easily expressed in terms of generator expressions or generators, or are implemented as iterators in C.  Either may also provide a `__copy__` mechanism that `itertools.tee` can actually use and won't bother duplicating work, either.  Only if its' really already an iterator that `tee` can't copy for you will it use space, doing all of the crystalizing for you.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do:

```
try:
    x = possible_generator.next()
    mylist = [x] + list(possible_generator)

except:
    pass
```

This will differentiate between generators and built-in iterables; however, if you have a custom class that is list-like but also implements next, then it would fail.

Comment: This also converts the generator into a list, which kind of defeats the purpose of using a generator in the first place.

Comment: but that's what he is trying to do...  he's going to walk it twice, so if it's already a list, keep the original, else flatten the generator into a list.

Comment: I missed that comment.