# Unpacking specific indexes

Tags: python, slice, iterable-unpacking

I want to retrieve specific indexes from an iterable. That would be equivalent to:

```
In [7]: def f():  
   ...:     return [1,2,3,4,5]  
In [8]: (_, x, _, y, _) =  f()  
In [9]: x, y  
Out[9]: (2, 4)
```

But I don't want to compute the iterable multiple times or it's very long and I don't want to write too many `_`s

My question is purely out of curiosity and I am actually using a local variables as shown above.

**EDIT**:

One solution is to simply use slicing with the notation `iterable[start:end:step]`:

```
In [24]: (x, y) =  f()[1:4:2]  
In [25]: x, y  
Out[25]: (2, 4)`
```

**EDDIT BIS**:
Using slicing works if you need to retrieve every `n`th elements in an iterable but if you want elements at index `2,3` and `5,6` using `operator.itemgetter(2,3,5,6)(lst)` seems to be a better solution:

```
In [8]: operator.itemgetter(2,3,5,6)(range(10))
Out[8]: (2, 3, 5, 6)
```

Comment: if you know the indexes you want, why not just use slicing?

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself?

Comment: @MattDMo slicing would work perfectly and can even work for non consecutive indexes if using the `iterable[start:end:step]` notation. Thanks just didn't thought about it !

Comment: also... not sure the context, but maybe see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503455/caching-a-generator if part of your issue is that you don't know if the input is an iterable or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One slightly roundabout way is to use the `itemgetter` function from the `operator` module.

```
 import operator
 m = operator.itemgetter(2,3)
 x, y = m([1,2,3,4,5])
```

The call to `itemgetter` creates a callable which takes an iterable `L` and returns `L[2]` and `L[3]`.